# How to form url for mysql connection in eclipse?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc

This is my url to access the php my admin page
http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/

How can I give it as connection details in eclipse?

Following URL doesn't work... getting error like ping failed

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: is DB database exist or not?

Comment: PHP My Admin is just an administration tool to connect to a MySQL database, it is not your MySQL database, nor does it provide any clues as to how or where your MySQL database is installed.